# How to have pie chart count based on distinct values of a column in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

In a database table I have something like this:

```
RatingID, StudentID, Sport, Rating
1, 1,     Tennis, 2
2, 1,     Tennis, 5
3, 2,     Basketball, 2
4, 2,     Basketball, 5
5, 3,     Basketball, 2
```

I want a pie chart that counts up how many people are playing each sport.
Currently, I am getting a pie chart using "Sport" that says:

```
BasketBall: 3
Tennis: 2
```

When I attempt to do a Distinct(SPORT), it says 1 for both. 
What I want to do is to be able to do a distinct on StudentID such that the pie chart says:

```
Tennis: 1
Basketball: 2
```

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `COUNTD` on `StudentID` not `Sport`. You would use `Sport` in the color card and the label card.

Like so:

[image]